# Could not find any vue.js file to link after installing vue NuGet package

Tags: asp.net-core, vue.js, nuget

I am trying to set up vue.js inside ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC web app in Visual Studio 2017 (the project will be co-developed also in Rider). The web app is NOT SPA. It has few static pages and few others with dynamic parts (like listing of items returned as a JSON list via an API). I would like to write these dynamic parts using vue.js.

I have found a [vue NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/vue/) and added it into the project. However, there is no vue.js-related file added into the project. I could not find any details how to use this package on the net. However, I have noticed this part in project.json which sounds that the files are somehow included in the package. But I have no idea how to reference them from my cshtml Master page.

```
"vue/2.5.16": {
  "sha512": "/GyGgghWxS/467eO3tEc4KPurjAgU1bfcvRk7pSyDFkI3J0QzaZyfnZkJQnyshsSdNc8CS8Z+/skmMETUI/79A==",
  "type": "package",
  "path": "vue/2.5.16",
  "files": [
    "Content/Scripts/vue.js",
    "Content/Scripts/vue.min.js",
    "vue.2.5.16.nupkg.sha512",
    "vue.nuspec"
  ]
},
```

What have I missed?

Comment: The Vue NuGet package uses a Content folder which is not supported with .NET Core projects. Files inside a Content folder will be added to projects that use a packages.config file. Projects that use PackageReferences are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with this in .NET6 the successor to ASP.NET Core. Basically you need to use NPM.

NPM is the recommended installation method for Vue. It pairs nicely with module bundlers such as Webpack or Browserify. Vue also provides accompanying tools for authoring Single File Components.

```
# latest stable
npm install vue
```

I tend to use NPM for Javascript packages and nuget for .NET libraries

You can also simply use the CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
```